# XNA C#: Projectile objects in a list under the Player class, NOT recognised by the Enemy class

Tags: c#, xna, 2d

Ok so I have a CollisionManager to Update my collisions. I have a Projectile class, a Player class and an Enemy class. Within the Player class, I created a list of projectiles (Projectile objs) which the Player class updates to increase or decrease their number. All is working great so far.

Now the problem, when checking for collision the Player obj is recognised by the Enemy obj. However, the Projectile obj is NOT recognised by the enemy, UNLESS I iterate through the whole projectiles list and manually check their colliders for intersection. It actually appears that the projectile colliders and non existent unless specifically checked for.

The code is below:

Player collision code (WORKING):

```
public override void OnCollision(Collidable obj)
{
    Enemies enemy = obj as Enemies;
    if (enemy != null)
      {
        health -= enemy.dmg; //if player collides with enemy, take dmg damage  
      }
}
```

Projectile collision code (WORKING):

```
public override void OnCollision(Collidable obj)
    {
        Enemies enemy = obj as Enemies;
        if (enemy != null)
        {
            exists = false;
            if (!exists) FlaggedForRemoval = true;
        }                               
    }
```

Enemy collision code (ONLY WORKING FOR PLAYER)

```
 public override void OnCollision(Collidable obj)
    {
        //Check collision with player
        Player pl = obj as Player;
        if (pl != null)
        {
           exists = false;
           ScoreManager.UpdateScore(pointsWorth);
        }

        //Check collision with projectile
        Projectile pr = obj as Projectile;
        if (pr != null)
        {
            health -= dmgReceived;
            if (health <= 0)
            {
                ScoreManager.UpdateScore(pointsWorth);
                exists = false;
                FlaggedForRemoval = true;
            }
        }

    }
```

The Enemy vs Projectile collision (for the enemy object - as proj works) is only working if during the Main.Update() if I iterate through the whole list of projectiles and manually check for collision with enemy

```
 foreach (Enemies e in enemyList)
                    {
                        e.Update(gameTime);
                        e.dmgReceived = player.dmg;


                        for (int i = 0; i < player.projList.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (player.projList[i].collider.Intersects(e.BoundingRectangle))
                            {

                               //Some code
                            }
                        }
```

So what is the problem? It seems to me that for some reason in the enemy collision code, the obj type is not recognised as Projectile maybe because it is in a List?

First time posting here, so I hope I did it right. Thanks for the help!

***UPDATE TO INCLUDE COLLISION CODE***

```
    public class Collidable
{
    protected Rectangle boundingRectangle = new Rectangle();
    public bool FlaggedForRemoval { get; protected set; }

    //Constructor
    public Collidable()
    {
        FlaggedForRemoval = false;
    }

    public Rectangle BoundingRectangle
    {
        get { return boundingRectangle; }
    }


    public virtual bool CollisionTest(Collidable obj)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public virtual void OnCollision(Collidable obj)
    {
    }
}
```

Collisions class:

```
public class CollisionComparer : IEqualityComparer<Collision>
{
    public bool Equals(Collision a, Collision b)
    {
        if ((a == null) || (b == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Collision a)
    {
        return a.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Collision
{
    public Collidable A;
    public Collidable B;

    public Collision(Collidable a, Collidable b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public bool Equals(Collision other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if ((this.A.Equals(other.A) && this.B.Equals(other.B))) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void Resolve()
    {
        this.A.OnCollision(this.B);
    }
}
```

Collision Manager class:

```
 public class CollisionManager
{

    //List of classes inheriting from Collidables
    private List<Collidable> m_Collidables = new List<Collidable>(); 

    //Hashset to collect all collisions in a single update
    private HashSet<Collision> m_Collisions = new HashSet<Collision>(new CollisionComparer()); 

    public void AddCollidable(Collidable c)
    {
        m_Collidables.Add(c);
    }

    public void RemoveCollidable(Collidable c)
    {
        m_Collidables.Remove(c);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        UpdateCollisions();
        ResolveCollisions();
    }

    //Check Collisions hashset

    private void UpdateCollisions()
    {
        if (m_Collisions.Count > 0) m_Collisions.Clear();

        //Iterate thgouh collidable objects to check for collisions
        for(int i =0; i<m_Collidables.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m_Collidables.Count; j++)
            {
                Collidable collidable1 = m_Collidables[i];
                Collidable collidable2 = m_Collidables[j];

                //Ensure we are not checking object with itself
                if (!collidable1.Equals(collidable2))
                {
                    //if two objects colliding then add them to the set
                    if (collidable1.CollisionTest(collidable2))
                    {
                        m_Collisions.Add(new Collision(collidable1, collidable2));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ResolveCollisions()
    {
        foreach (Collision c in m_Collisions)
        {
            c.Resolve();
        }
    }

}
```

Based on the above code, the Collision Detection for these three classes (Player, Enemy, Projectile) is:

```
   //Collision Detection
    public override bool CollisionTest(Collidable obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            return collider.Intersects(obj.BoundingRectangle);
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

I update all collisions using collisionManager.Update() in the game's main.Update().

I am sorry for the lengthy code!

**UPDATE 2 SHOWING PROJECTILES ADDED TO LIST**

both the below are under the Player class with the UpdateProjectile being part of the player.Update();

```
 public void PlayerShoots()
    {
        //Fire only if projectile delay resets
        if (projDelay >= 0)
            projDelay--;

        // if projectile delay is at 0 then create a new projectile(add to list)
        if(projDelay <=0)
        {

            Projectile newProj = new Projectile(projTexture);
            collisionManager.AddCollidable(newProj);
            newProj.position = new Vector2(position.X + 100 - newProj.texture.Width / 2, position.Y ); //+ newProj.texture.Height/10
            newProj.collider = new Rectangle((int)newProj.position.X, (int)newProj.position.Y, newProj.texture.Width, newProj.texture.Height);
            newProj.exists = true;


            if (projList.Count() < 80)
            {
                projList.Add(newProj);

            }
        }

        //reset projectile delay
        if (projDelay == 0)
            projDelay = 50;
    }
```

And

```
// update projectile functioN
    public void UpdateProjectile()
    {
        // for each projectile in the list update its position and remove it if it reaches right screen boundary
        foreach(Projectile p in projList)
        {
            //Update collider for every projectile in our list
            p.collider = new Rectangle((int)p.position.X, (int)p.position.Y, p.texture.Width, p.texture.Height);
           //Projectile motion
            p.position.X = p.position.X + p.speed+1;
            if (p.position.X >= 1118)
                p.exists = false;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<projList.Count; i++)
        {
            if(!projList[i].exists)
            {
                projList.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you check for collisions at all? From what I see here, you have a method that is called upon collision, but you are not telling us how the collision is evaluated. If you do not check for the projectiles in the calling method, how should this method work with them? The collision detection has to be made at some point and these methods you gave us are not a collision detection, they are the result of a collision detection.

Comment: Why don't you just edit your original post?

Comment: Just did! Sorry, only realised later :)

Comment: Okay, you now did post a whole lot of new code which tells me: You never check for collisions between projectiles and enemies in your `CollisionManager` class. You may want to move the projectiles into a list that is not part of the player class and that can be accessed by the `CollisionManager` in order to be correctly represented by the collision detection.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer! I have another question. Why isn't the list under the player accessed through the CollisionManager? As I understand it, I create a list of Projectile objects in the Player class and as each object is created, it is also added to the collidables through collisionManager.AddCollidable(newProj).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I completely missed that you add colliders to the `CollisionManager`! Well, have you stepped through your code with the debugger and checked if they are in the list? Also, I do not see a line of code where you add them to the `CollisionManager`. Do you have that line somewhere?

Comment: I have now updated the code :) It seems that the list is ok, since when I manually iterate through it and check for collision with each enemy on enemy list, the collisions work :/

Comment: Alright, could it be that you need to add `B.OnCollision(A);` to the `Resolve` method of `Collision`? So far it looks like the projectiles are checked with the enemy, but not vice versa.

Comment: tried it but doesnt work either. I think it may have something to do with not recognising the projectile objects in the 'List' as of type "Projectile' implicitly. I will try creating a ProjectileManager tomorrow and have the list under there. See if that works :) Thank you very much for all the effort! Let me know if you think of something else in the meantime